# 3.3 Geo nodes, Hair Curves. How to make the thickness have a tapered tip?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, hair

I'm seeing a lot of posts with the new Hair curve, for creating hair. I found how to make thickness with geometry nodes but, I don't know how to add a profile to make the tip pointy, and tapered. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 3):

You can see it briefly in the [official video](https://youtu.be/6_USH9c_vNU?t=1358). They use a *Geometry Nodes* modifier for the new *Hair Curve* object with a *Float Curve* node. It defines the thickness profile of the hair from the root to the tip.

The *Map Range* node is used to scale the root and tip values individually and to have them in the order, root first, then tip.

[image: example]

Don't forget to enter values for the group inputs in the *Geometry Node* modifier's settings (see screenshot on the right side). The values depend on the size of your model. For a default cube, try something like `0.03` for the root and `0.0` (or `0.01`) for the tip.

**Important Setting for the Viewport and Eevee**

To see the thickness of the hair curves in the viewport and *Eevee* rendered images you need to set the *[Curves > Shape](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/render_settings/hair.html)* option to `Strip`. (In older Blender versions *Curves* is labeled as *Hair*)

> `Strand` = Render curves as a thin strand roughly a pixel wide. **Curve diameter parameters are ignored with this setting.**
>
> `Strip` = Render curves as a flat ribbon with rounded normals.

*Cycles* always respects the cure diameter parameters.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll check this out.

Comment: Unfortunately I set this up but its not working. No thickness is showing. that odd. I did all settings right. https://ibb.co/30N3SxP

Comment: Hi. Why do you have the Group Input slots *To Min* and *To Max* 2 times? You can remove them in the side panel of the node editor. Select the vertical *Group* tab. Do you have entered values for the group inputs in the modifier's settings (see my screenshot, on the right side). Try `0.03` for the root and `0.0` for the tip. The values depend on the size of your model. Oops, I forgot to mention the *Eevee* setting... Give me a second.

Comment: Make sure to set the *Curves > Shape* option to *Strip*. Otherwise, you will see the effect only when you render with Cycles.

Comment: I can not delete the double Max/ Min, I forget how I got them exactly. I unplugged them and re- plugged them in and it added 2 .. I think. I tried in the N, vertical panel aria, I don't see how to deletes them

Comment: Wow!! Its working!! Thanks you so much!! I still could not reset the Map range node...even when I bring in a new one, its still has double Max/Min. hmm. But, Im so excited to make hair now!!

Comment: so unfort when rendering in Cycles. some of the tips are not pointed.. ? Any idea of why? https://ibb.co/ZHj3SW7 it does not happen in Evee @Blunder

Comment: I haven't seriously tried to create a hairstyle yet and haven't encountered this. Keep in mind that Blender 3.3 is still in development (alpha version). There might be bugs and not everything is implemented yet. Do you use the latest version? As long it's in the alpha state the version is basically built daily. The official release of Blender 3.3 is on 7th September 2022.

Comment: excellent - thanks