# How do I smooth out hair to make it look more like a curve?

Tags: hair

Is there a geometry node for it?  The comb only works when you want straight hair.  I want mine to be curly but it keeps giving me street lines.

[image]

Is there a geometry node I can make them more curvy?  The best result I had is connecting this to a Curve to Mesh node.  But this isn't really hair is it?  How do I get rid of the straight lines in my first photo?

[image]

Here is me just adding ONE hair.  It is not smooth at all, why are there so many straight lines?
[image]

Here is me adding a Curve to Mesh Node.  This is what I want.  Anyone know how I can make my hair look like this without converting it into a mesh?  Because I don't think this is good if it stays as a mesh?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Smooth Out the Hair Curves

There is an option for both render engines *Eevee* and *Cycles* that allows hair curves to be displayed with additional subdivisions. The default value is *2* for *Cycles* and *0* for *Eevee*. (Maybe for performance reasons, since Eevee is also used for the *Material Preview* mode.)

Just increase ***Curves > Additional Subdivision*** to `2` for *Eevee*. It's also a good idea to set ***Curves > Shape*** to `Strip` to see the actual size of the hair and not just a thin line.

[image: screenshot]

**Note:** The *Hair thickness* shown above is an extra *Geometry Nodes* modifier that sets the radius of the hair curves. You will still need the *Surface Deform* modifier or at least the *[Deform Curves on Surface](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/270962/107598)* node to make the hair work properly with other modifiers.

### Eevee Hair Shader (Addendum)

[image: blonde hair shader]
(Reference image from [41 Blonde Hair Color Ideas, From Golden To Caramel](https://blog.wella.com/us/blonde-hair-colors))

The *Curves* object usually uses the material in the first slot if you assign one. But you can also use the *Set Material* node in the *Geometry Nodes* node tree to set a material ([example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/270106/107598)).

The *Principled Hair BSDF* node is for *Cycles* only. So for *Eevee* you have to create your own shader mix. A simple node setup is a *Diffuse Shader* mixed with two *Glossy Shaders* (the part on the right).

[image: Eevee Hair Shader nodes]

The part on the left is to match a more natural color variation of hair. It's a bunch of *Mix*, *ColorRamp*, and the *Curve Info* nodes (in older Blender versions they are called *MixRBG* and *Hair Info* nodes). In addition, you can add a distorted normal map to create a very subtle variation in reflection. Got it from [Einar's beard shader](https://studio.blender.org/films/charge/?asset=6072).

To dye a single hair strand you can use a painted image texture instead of the *Musgrave Texture* that is used in this example. You need to UV map it as shown here: [New Hair Curves: Getting color from emitter object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/280096/107598)

Comment: Thank you!!!  Last question, how do you change the hair shader?  There is a Hair BSDF shader, but that only works in cycles.  What about Eevee?  Are we using principle shader?

Comment: For Eevee, you have to create your own shader mix. I've updated my answer post above. The color variation part can also be used for Cycles' Principled Hair BSDF node. Note that you can have 2 *Material Output* nodes, one for Eevee and one for Cycles, in the same material node tree. Have fun with hair coloring!